# Set Toolbar position in View when hide the TabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uitabbarcontroller, toolbar

I have an iPhone Application, that uses a Navigation controller and TabBar controller.

In a first view, I show an a tableview, and when I click on first tableview cell, I set a new view with new Toolbar and without TabBar.

The new view correctly shows the toolbar, but this is far from 40px down, as if it were always leaving the seat to the previous TabBar.

In that regard, I saw that Interface Builder sets the size of the view in 320 x 460, and not with the classic 320 x 480. Unfortunately they are not editable fields (they are grayed out as if it were a lock). Why?

Images:

iPhone APP

[image: iPhone APP]
http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/5717/schermata20110531a00243.jpg

Interface Builder Options

[image: Interface Builder Options]
http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/2817/schermata20110531a00250.png

Thanks,
Alessandro from Italy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `TRUE` before you push the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The 20px difference is the height of status bar. You can set if the view been shown with or without a status bar from the view's property pane of IB.

Comment: The white bottom space is not 20px, but is the same size of TabBar. How set the toolbar at the bottom, without the white space?

Comment: Your tabBar is in some superview of your navigation's controller stack. You need to re-organize your view hierarchy, to move the tabBar making it a subview of rootviewcontroller of the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface builder, try placing the toolbar at the bottom of the view and adjust the stud to keep it at the bottom(turn on the bottom stud on), this will help surely.